# Youtube data api in asp.net mvc or asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does any one know YouTube Data API?

If I enter a channel name in a textbox, that channel's recently uploaded videos should show in a list format.

The code needs to be in either Asp.Net or MVC.

Comment: Welcome - please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. to improve your question.

Comment: fixed language/grammar